# Where is the .dSYM file when building a Xamarin Forms 5 iOS with a Azure Devops Mac Build Agent

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm using an Azure Devops Pipeline to build our Xamarin Forms 5.x app.

We have a self hosted DevOps agent installed on a mac which is used to build the iOS project, then we push the .ipa file up to App Center.

What I'd like to do is also push up the .dSYM file so we can get symbolicated crash reports.

I cannot find a .dSYM file in any of the agents folders, Microsoft's help file doesn't help [iOS Symbolication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/diagnostics/iOS-symbolication), any suggestions where I can find this file?

The build tasks for my pipeline look like:

```yaml
- task: XamariniOS@2
  displayName: 'Build Xamarin.iOS solution'
  inputs:
    solutionFile: '**/*.sln'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
    buildForSimulator: false
    packageApp: true

- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files to Artifact Staging Directory'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    Contents: '**/*.ipa'
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    flattenFolders: true

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact iOS'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'iOS'
    publishLocation: Container
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution for Visual Studio:**

If you have enabled device-specific builds, the .dSYM can be found in the following directory:

```
<project directory>/bin/<platform>/<configuration>/device-builds/<device>-<os-version>/
```

For example:

```
TestApp/bin/iPhone/Release/device-builds/iphone8.4-11.3.1/
```

If you have not enabled device-specific builds, the .dSYM can be found in the following directory:

```
<project directory>/bin/<platform>/<configuration>/
```

For example:

```
TestApp/bin/iPhone/Release/
```

**Solution for Xcode:**

In general, if there is no human modification, the DSYM file will be stored in

```
`~/Library/Developer/Xcode`
```

You can use the find command to find all .dSYM files under the current pat

```
 allFiles=`find ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives -iname '*.dSYM'`
```

Of course, if you want to be more precise, you can add the upper -type parameter :

```
filesPath=`find ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives -iname '*.dSYM' -type f`
```

Comment: Not sure this helps, there is no .dSYM files in these paths, I'm not even sure whether the Azure Devops Agent uses Xcode to do the build or it uses Visual Studio for mac. I'll post my pipeline steps

Comment: @vbtrek Hi, I changed my answer.

Comment: @guangyu-bai-msft thanks for the reply, I have now found the dSYM folder, just seems to be something odd with the Agent that is cleaning up after itself. Posted a reply with details.

Comment: If you think this is a good answer you can mark it and other people can refer to this.

Answer (score 0):

So I have found the dSYM folder, and it was in the Azure DevOps Mac Build Agent's _work folder (as per the Visual Studio Folders mentioned in @guangyu-bai-msft in the above post).

The reason I could not see the folder on the Azure DevOps Mac Build Agents _work folder after the build is something to do with the agent which seems to be moving some of the output files from:

```
<project directory>/bin/<platform>/<configurtion>
```

To the Agents binary folder:

```
_work\1\b
```

Then the Agent deletes the bin and obj folders under the project.

This is not a step I've added to my Pipeline, and I cannot see it logged by any of the steps, so I can only assume it's the Agent doing this. As long as I zip/copy the dSYM folder before the Pipeline stage finishes it works fine.

I've added a step as follows to the pipeline after CopyFiles@2 on the original post:

```yaml
- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/archive-files-v2?view=azure-pipelines&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops
  displayName: 'Compress dSYM Folder to Artifact Staging Directory'
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/<path to project>/bin/iPhone/Release/<project name>.app.dSYM'
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/<project name>.app.dSYM.zip'
    replaceExistingArchive: true
```

Comment: Yes, I noticed this. But I am not familiar with Pipeline. So I prefer you to ask a new question. Someone else might know this problem.